# Wait for multiple async calls to finish in RxJava

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, reactive-programming

My scenario is quite simple, but I don't seem to able to find it anywhere.

I have a set of elements that I want to iterate through, for each one call an async function, and then wait for all of them to finish (which again happens in an asynchronous fashion, implemented in the logic of the function). I'm relatively new to RxJava and used to do this easily in NodeJS by passing callback to the function and wait at the end. 
Here's the pseudocode of what I need (the iterator for elements does not need to be synchronous nor ordered):

```
for(line in lines){
 callAsyncFunction(line);
}
WAIT FOR ALL OF THEM TO FINISH
```

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Pls post the actual code. RxJava has so many operators with different behaviours. Without knowing what operator you use, it is impossible to help.

Comment: Use countdownlatch class, and in oncomplete method of every observable call countDown method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Rx:

```
Observable
.from(lines)
.flatMap(line -> callAsyncFunctionThatReturnsObservable(line).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.ignoreElements();
```

At this point, depending on what you want to do you can use an `.switchIfEmpty(...)` to subscribe to another observable.

Comment: Nice! super elegant

Answer (score 3):

Well technically if you think about it, what you need to do is create an Observable from all of your elements, and then [zip them together](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) to continue your stream's execution.

That would in pseudocode give you something like this:

```
List<Observable<?>> observables = new ArrayList<>();
for(line in lines){
   observables.add(Observable.fromCallable(callAsyncFunction(line));
}
Observable.zip(observables, new Function<...>() { ... }); // kinda like Promise.all()
```

But it might come as no surprise that `Observable.from()` can expose every element within an iterable as a stream of objects, thus eliminating your need for a loop. So you could create a new Observable that calls `onCompleted()` when the async operation is complete, using `Observable.fromCallable()`. Afterwards, you can wait for these new Observables by collecting them into a list.

```
Observable.from(lines)
   .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(String line) {
            return Observable.fromCallable(callAsyncFunction(line)); // returns Callable
        }
    }).toList()
      .map(new Func1<List<Object>, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(List<Object> ignored) {
            // do something;
        }
    });
```

I'm basing this second half of my answer heavily on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35365371/2413303).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Iterable of "items to compute" into an Iterable of Observables using [defer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#defer-rx.functions.Func0-), and then [zip](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip-rx.Observable:A-rx.functions.FuncN-) on the Observables.

The more difficult part will be "waiting for them all to finish". As you may have guessed, Reactive Extensions are about "reacting" to stuff, not "waiting for stuff to happen." You can [subscribe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribe-rx.functions.Action1-rx.functions.Action1-rx.functions.Action0-) to the observable, which will emit a single item and then complete if each observable has only one item. That subscriber can do whatever action you would normally do after the wait; this allows you to return and let your code do its thing without blocking on it.