# Multiple Observable execution with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I have two Observables define and I am calling them as below:

```
Observable<Boolean> statusObser1 = reactiveApiConsumer.syncGradesSet1(subListDtos.get(0));
Observable<Boolean> statusObser2 = reactiveApiConsumer.syncGradesSet2(subListDtos.get(1));
statusObser1.toBlocking().first();
statusObser2.toBlocking().first();
```

But the problem is that `statusObser2` executes only after `statusObser1` has completed. Instead I want both observers to execute in parallel, i.e. `statusObser2` shouldn't wait for `statusObser1` to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They execute sequentially since you're blocking (`toBlocking()`) and waiting for their response.

Instead, subscribe to them. Either individually:

```
Observable<Boolean> statusObser1 = ...
Observable<Boolean> statusObser2 = ...
statusObser1.subscribe(System.out::println); //Example
statusObser2.subscribe(System.out::println); //Example
```

Or using the Zip operator:

```
public static int doSomethingWithBothValues(Boolean a, Boolean b) {
    ...
}

...

Observable<Boolean> statusObser1 = ...
Observable<Boolean> statusObser2 = ...
Observable.zip(statusObser1,statusObser2, this::doSomethingWithBothValues);
```

see more details about the Zip operator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357919/combine-a-list-of-observables-and-wait-until-all-completed/35363084#35363084).

In both cases, if the observables are asynchronous, they will be executed in parallel.

There are other operators you can use to combine the results of both your operators without blocking either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try MultiThreading.

```
Observable<Boolean> statusObser1 = reactiveApiConsumer.syncGradesSet1(subListDtos.get(0));
Observable<Boolean> statusObser2 = reactiveApiConsumer.syncGradesSet2(subListDtos.get(1));
startThread(statusObser1);
startThread(statusObser2);

public void startThread(Observable<Boolean> statusObser) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            statusObser.toBlocking().first();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

`startThread` method will execute the execution in a new Thread, and both executions wil executed in seperate Thread.

Comment: That's a very bad solution. It completely misses the point of using *Reacive* programming techniques.