# How to combine all Firebase ML kit APIs in one app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I want that if one image is selected it detects Label, text and faces in single image at one time only.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call all of the functions on your image file at once, then combine the results using something like [zip in RXJava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35363084/608312).

Alternatively, you could nest the results (e.g. call `FirebaseVision.getInstance().onDeviceTextRecognizer.processImage(image)` inside the `onSuccessListener` of another function), although this will take much longer to complete all.

If you provide code of your existing attempts, StackOverflow can help further.