# Firebase ML-Kit multi detectors

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

How to recognize barcode and text with one camera source (at the same time) with Firebase ML kit on Android? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358301/how-to-combine-all-firebase-ml-kit-apis-in-one-app) you can combine the results using [Zip Operator](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip%28java.lang.Iterable,%20rx.functions.FuncN%29) or nest your processes inside `onSuccessListener` of the other function.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?